# How to stop VS Code from truncating Python data in the console?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm opening a csv file in VS Code with Python. Your basic `csv import`. I know the complete csv data is reading properly because it's printing to macOS Terminal via Anaconda iPython as expected.

However, when I print the csv data to `VS Code Interactive Window` or `VS Code iPython Window` VS Code is truncating the data.  It's not printing the csv header row and it's also truncating the length of the rest of the csv data and/or it starts the data output at some deep row like around row 1000.

The issue is not in code because it's printing fine in Terminal/iPython.

Naturally, I'm using the standard Microsoft Python extension and the iPython extension. The problem persists even when disabling one of them.

Is this a VS Code default preference issue?

**VS Code Interactive Window** 
No header and following data is truncated both at beginning and end.
[image]
**VS Code iPython Truncation**
Again, no header, plus truncation.
[image]
Terminal/Conda iPython all good. Header and following data. 
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to go to the Settings of the Python extension in VSCode and locate this setting:

```
Python › Data Science: Text Output Limit
Limit the amount of text in Python Interactive cell text output to this value. 0 to allow any amount of characters.
```

By default (for whatever reason) that is set to 2000. Change it to 0 to allow any number of characters showing in the output.

Comment: Was having the same issue with Jupyter notebooks in vscode and this solved it. Thanks!

Comment: So sorry. Been so busy I never even noticed I didn't mark this correct after all this time. I also upvoted it. Great answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [data viewer in our Jupyter support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_variable-explorer-and-data-viewer).

Answer (score -1):

Recently I had been running into this same issue, but VSCode and the Python extension has moved the Data Science functionality to the Jupyter extension by now. To solve this, I refer to [my answer to the same issue elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837463/9204693).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).