# VSCode interactive python output exceeds size limit

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, jupyter, ipython, settings

When I use VSCode interactive Python, sometimes I get this message:

`Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor`

This has links to settings and the text editor. However, the text editor, my usual option, is littered with unicode symbols that are not being rendered and is completely unreadable (it should be showing the traceback for an error).

Meanwhile, the settings do not contain a Max Output Size for Jupyter, which was suggested in this post: [VS Code and Jupyter Notebook - how to open large output in text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68331861/vs-code-and-jupyter-notebook-how-to-open-large-output-in-text-editor)

What can I do to get the traceback displayed in full?

Comment: If you open VSCode's settings and search for 'Max Output Size', you don't find the setting mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68331861/vs-code-and-jupyter-notebook-how-to-open-large-output-in-text-editor? I find this setting, and  changing it provides the expected result. But it has a note stating 'This setting is deprecated and will be removed in the next release.'

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Jupyter extension currently notes the following regarding the 'Max Output Size' setting:

> This setting is deprecated in favor of `notebook.output.textLineLimit`. This setting will be removed in an upcoming release.

The setting they are referring to is 'Notebook > Output: Text Line Limit' which requires you to reload VSCode before changes are applied. Also note that the previous setting used 0 to indicate that the output is unlimited, while the new setting does not. So, if you want to see exceptionally large outputs, then you will need to fill in an enormous number. Personally, I limit my output to 1000 lines because I find that any output larger than that either should be split up or written to a file.

Answer (score -5):

what you should do is install a dependency in Visual Studio before making your code and it is this:
`!pip install openpyxl`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).