# for-loop error : "Output exceeds the size limit." (VSCode)

Tags: python, for-loop, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I was trying to make a for loop to sum the integers from 1 to 100 in Python and wrote the code like this :

```
for i in range(1, 101) :
    sum_list = []
    sum_list.append(i)
    print(sum(sum_list))
```

but it didn't print the output I wanted (5050) and the VSCode python interpreter showed the message that output exceeded the size limit.

I want to know what causes this error and what I should do if I want to get the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not getting the result because you were initializing the list inside the for loop. You need to initialize in the beginning before starting for loop.

```
sum_list = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    sum_list.append(i)

print(sum(sum_list))
#5050
```

2.You can get the result my list comprehension as well.

```
sum_list=[i for i in range(1,101)]
print(sum(sum_list))
#5050
```

3.another way:

```
sum_list=list(range(1,101))
print(sum(sum_list))
#5050
```

4.Directly sum generator expression:

```
sum(i for i in range(1,101))
#5050
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re not getting the output you expect (`5050`) because the list needs to be initialized before you begin iterating through integers.

For example:

```py
sum_list = []

for i in range(1, 101):
    sum_list.append(i)

print(sum(sum_list))
```

As far as the error goes, it seems to be a visual code extension’s config. It’s likely due to you printing out the sum of every iteration. I found a similar question on stackoverflow, perhaps the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837463/17597213) could help you as well. I’d recommend checking your VSCode / extension settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting a size limit exception, those only occur when you want to output some very large data (and i think in a jupyter notebook). but for starters I would move the `sum_list` creation out of the for loop.

```py
sum_list = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    sum_list.append(i)
    print(sum(sum_list))
```

This worked for me, but I didn't get your error when i ran your code, so